# Ubuntu Server - Minimal Virtual Machine AND OEM Install?

Tags: server, lts, oem

When you boot from the Ubuntu Server (LTS) and Press F4 for more options, you can choose the "Minimal Virtual Machine" option, which essentially installs a JeOS Ubuntu, with a reduced HD&memory footprint.

It is also possible to do a OEM installation, by pressing F4 for more options, and selecting OEM installation.  This allows to easily make base installations that can be finished later (i.e. set hostname, packages, language, etc).

However, I find no documentation on how you can make a "OEM Minimal Virtual Machine" installation.  Selecting Minimal Virtual and then selecting OEM installation doesn't seem to work.

I'd like to make Minimal Virtual Machine installations OEM, so I can export an OVA template for re-utilization amongst our system administrators here.  That would save some time.

I know that OEM boot option is:

> oem-config/enable=true

But I've tried to find the boot options for JeoS (Minimal Virtual Machine), and I can't find any.

Do anyone know the boot options to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is no direct answer but maybe the [JEOS vmbuilder](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html) will help you to achieve that task? Even though the article appears to be from 12.04 [vmbuilder](https://launchpad.net/vmbuilder) is still released and up to date.